# Aspose Words - remove only part of bookmarks

Tags: java, aspose.words

I have a problem with deleting bookmarks & paragraphs.

Bookmarks: **SUB_1**, **SUB_2**, **SUB_3**, **SUB_4**, **SUB_5**.

After loop execution, are deleted only **SUB_1, SUB_3** and **SUB_5**.

```
            BookmarkCollection bookmarks = doc.getRange().getBookmarks();
            DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

            System.out.println(bookmarks.getCount()); 

            for(Bookmark b : bookmarks) {
                System.out.println("bookmark: " + b.getName());
                builder.moveToBookmark(b.getName());
                builder.getCurrentParagraph().remove(); 
            }
```

output:

```
10:13:10,379 INFO  [stdout] 5

10:13:10,380 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 8) bookmark: SUB_1

10:13:10,381 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 8) bookmark: SUB_3

10:13:10,382 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 8) bookmark: SUB_5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use bookmark.remove() method to delete bookmarks instead of moving cursor to paragraph and then removing that paragraph.

I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem. It isn't quite good, but it's work for me.

```
        BookmarkCollection bookmarks = doc.getRange().getBookmarks();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
            while(bookmarks.getCount() > 0) {
                for(Bookmark b : bookmarks) {
                    System.out.println("bookmark: " + b.getName());
                    b.setText("");
                    builder.moveToBookmark(b.getName());
                    builder.getCurrentParagraph().remove(); 
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Problem with deleting bookmark");
        }
```